# iPhone stack scroll view

Tags: iphone

I have implemented stack scroll view in iphone using  [this blog](http://www.raweng.com/blog/stack-scroll-view/).
but i am facing one problem
When user is clicking on details view i want show detailview on complete screen.
When user is clicking on it again i want show show it like default stack scroll view with menu option.

I am trying this but not getting any success, have any one tried same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make custom Scrollview, then you will get separate touch event.

I think this may solve your problem.